# Spring Kafka - Consumer Factory for multiple model classes

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have recently started learning Kafka and I'm trying to make basic communication between two springboot microservices.

Currently I have a model class User. I am sending the User object from one Producer service and receiving the same on separate Consumer service via Kafka.
I have configured the ConsumerFactory in the following way:

```
public class User{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String place;
   // getters, setters
}
```

Consumer Config:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig{

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, User> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"group1");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringSerializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class));
   }

   @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> 
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory =
          new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

This is working properly and I am able to deserialize the User object in the consumer service.

Now suppose if I have 20 more such model classes such as Product, Order, Payment etc. Do I need to create ConsumerFactory for each of model classes as JsonDeserializer constructor takes the target class type as parameter in
`return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringSerializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class));`

Is there any generic way of doing this for all model classes?

Appreciate all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sender is also Spring, the `JsonSerializer` will add type information in headers that the deserializer uses to deserialize (by default); the generic parameter is only used when no type information is available in the headers (or using type headers is disabled).

If the model is in different packages on the producer and consumer, then you can add type mapping configuration to map the consumer type to the producer type.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde

And https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types

Comment: Hi Gary, what my main doubt was do I need to create 10 different ConsumerFactory for 10 different model classes as JsonDeserializer needs a target class? Is there any way I can create only one ConsumerFactory that can be used while deserializing for all 10 model class?

Comment: As I explained, the type comes from the headers, so you only need one factory/deserializer; the generic type `<User>` is only used if there are no type headers; you can make it `<Object>` because the sending side will include type information in the headers.

Comment: I had to disable the headers because while deserializing in Consumer service it was throwing me `ClassNotFoundException` . It was searching for `com.demo.Producer.Product` class during deserializing while it was `com.demo.Consumer.Product` in Consumer service. I had created an exact replica of model class in both the services. So if I add Json mapping for these two classes, so do I need to do such mappings for all other 10 model classes as well?

Comment: Yes, you will need to configure type mappings for each type.